# Where should the template directory be for Django Haystack?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm following [Haystack tutorial](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html) and trying to adapt it to my project. It says

> You’ll need to create a new template inside your template directory called search/indexes/myapp/note_text.txt and place the following inside:

But I have put this in the 3 places I can think it might mean, but I still get [TemplateDoesNotExist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnVGD.png).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show us your projects directory structure (a screenshot or text description) and your variable `TEMPLATES` in your settings file?

Comment: I’ve already included a screenshot of the project directory together with the error code. Ill edit the post with the templates variable in a few

Comment: The error looks for `cards_text.txt` all lowercase, but I see in your screenshot that you have it capitalized as `Cards_text.txt` in one place. Could you fix that an see what happens?

Comment: That fixed it @Ralf! I chose capital letter because the name of my model is with a capital in browser->models. I get a different error, but that is easily fixed. Could you post your comment as answer so I can choose it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments to the question:

In the stacktrace that can be seen in the screenshot, the error message says it cannot find the template `.../cards_text.txt`; notice how the name is all lowercase.

But the project structure that can be seen in the same screenshot shows a file named `.../Cards_text.txt`; notice how the name starts with a capital letter.

You could either fix your code or rename the file.